# RS232 Communication protocols

Tags: flutter, serial-port

I want to show my inverter data in my Flutter app. I have successfuly established a connection between app and device through RS232.My question is how to calculate CRC and in which format to send the Query? The Query command is `^P005GS\<CRC\>\<cr\>`

Comment: You'd have to find how to calculate the CRC in the inverter protocol reference.

Comment: Do you get a response back when you send the query?  Is it an ASCII protocol or binary?  Did you search to see if there's already a python module that will communicate with your inverter?  What do you mean "I've successfully established a connection"?  How do you know?